# Iterating trough array and sending http request dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay, I have this array `pokemonColor=['name1', 'name2', 'name3']`. How can I iterate trough this array and dynamically send http request so I can update state like this below? Because this what I am trying does not work, it creates a JavaScript object, but too many of them...

This is what I want:

```
this.state.pokemon:[ 
    {name: name1, img: img1},
    {name: name2, img: img2},
    {name: name3, img: img3} 
]
```

And this is how I am trying:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // console.log(this.state.pokemonColor);
    this.state.pokemonColor.forEach(pok => {

      axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pok}/`).then(res => {
        // console.log(res.data.sprites.front_shiny);


        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          pokemon: {
            name: res.data.name,
            img: res.data.sprites.front_shiny
          }
        });
      });
    });
    // console.log(this.state.pokemon);
  }
```

Comment: `this.state.pokemon` mutates state directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - `this.state.pokemon = [...]` mutates the state directly. Your app may crash or at least you will receive a long, red error in your console.

Secondly - you don't have to destructure `state` inside `setState` function.

Thirdly - with every axios `get` request, you are overwriting `pokemon` field in your state. I'd suggest you to keep your `pokemons` inside array.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
   pokemon: [
      ...prevState.pokemon,
      {
         name: res.data.name,
         img: res.data.sprites.front_shiny,
      },
   ],
});
```

Then you will be able to access your `pokemons` by referencing to `this.state.pokemons`, which will be an array of objects.

Comment: Hi @kind user, currently the array that I am performing forEach on has 40 items (names). When I  console.log(res.data.sprites.front_shiny); inside an http request, it logs 40 images from all of the names inside the array, the same with the names. Thats all good, but when i try to set state like you suggested it logs over 300 objects and every object has one object more inside than the previous one... Thats my problem, I do not know how update the state... Does this have some thing to do with componentDidUpdate life cycle or?

Comment: It was  componentDidUpdate that was making a problem for me... When I did this in a separate function and then call that function where I needed, it all works fine now with updating the state the way you suggested .... Thank you very much!

Comment: @SecondClassCitizen I forgot to tell you that you cant use `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillUpdate` since it will end with a infinite loop. Im happy that u fixed it. :)